# JavaFX TableView how to add items to column?

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, javafx

I've working on a GUI that the user can browse text files from the SYSTEM and then when the user press "Start" button the program reading the text file/s, create lists from its data and supposed to add it to `TableView`. I'm stuck on inserting the data from the lists to the table. I've created the columns names by file names and added it to table:

```
tblConfigurationSystemColumns.add("Parameter Name");
tblSystemColumn.stream().map((str) -> str.split("PCM")).forEachOrdered((a) -> {
tblConfigurationSystemColumns.add(a[0].trim());
        });
for (int i = 0; i < tblConfigurationSystemColumns.size(); i++) {
    TableColumn col = new TableColumn(tblConfigurationSystemColumns.get(i));
    tableConfigurationSystem.getColumns().addAll(col);        
}
```

The column names coming from the list `tblConfigurationSystemColumns`. This list may be changed from each use of the GUI by number of file you browse from the system. (for now let think that we have 2 strings inside: `"column1","column2"`)

I need to add items to `column1` from the list `SysParameter` , and to `column2` from list `SysValues`.

How can I add values from each list to each column by rows?
If you need any more code please tell me (just let you know, the only code that I have it the list creating from the files).

***EDIT:***
[image]

This is what I got after the column building.
after this I need to get the "Parameter" and the "Value" for each column(as you can see).
I've made a list that get the "Parameter" from the text file, and another list that get the "Value" from the text file.

how can I put each list to it's column?
This is the code that build this lists:

```
            boolean inCESystem = false;
        for (final String line : list) {
    if (line.contains("CE-") && !(line.contains("CE-system-equipment-pm") || line.contains("inbound") || line.contains("outbound"))) {
        inCESystem = true;
    }
    else if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        inCESystem = false;
    }
    else if (inCESystem) {
        CE_System.add(line);
    }
        }
        boolean inCESystemInbound = false;
        for (final String line : list) {
    if (line.contains("CE-") && (line.contains("inbound")) ) {
        inCESystemInbound = true;
    }
    else if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        inCESystemInbound = false;
    }
    else if (inCESystemInbound) {
        CE_System.add("inbound_loadlock - "+line.trim());
    }
        }
        boolean inCESystemOutbound = false;
        for (final String line : list) {
    if (line.contains("CE-") && (line.contains("outbound")) ) {
        inCESystemOutbound = true;
    }
    else if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        inCESystemOutbound = false;
    }
    else if (inCESystemOutbound) {
        CE_System.add("outbound_loadlock - "+line.trim());
    }
        }            
        /*
         * Check the CE list to split each object per parameter and value to different lists
         */
        CE_System.stream().map((str) -> str.split(",")).map((a) -> {
            CE_SystemParameter.add(a[0].trim()); //Parameters
            return a;
        }).forEachOrdered((a) -> {
            if(a.length > 1) {
                CE_System_Value.add(a[1].trim()); //Values
            } else {
                CE_System_Value.add(""); //add blank if parameter doesn't have value
            } 
        });
```

***EDIT 2:*** Text file example

```
CE-system:
   No features to set for this item...

CE-system-componentmanager:
   Bootstrap Parallelism                             ,Parallel Bootstrapping

CE-system-components:
   No features to set for this item...

CE-system-components-accessmanager:
   Access control enable                             ,disabled
   Access policy prototyping                         ,enabled
   Access user group                                 ,enabled
   Implicit roles access policy                      ,disabled
   World access policy                               ,disabled

CE-system-components-eqlog:
   EquipmentLog Enable                               ,false
```

- Line that contains "CE-" its just title to know that is should be in the "Configuration" Tab.
- each line inside is the "parameter" and the value(after the comma).

***EDIT 3:*** The table should look like this example (This example is from my code in Java SWT)
[image]

Thank you very much guys.

Comment: You add the data to the `TableView` (using the `items` property). You customize this by setting the `cellValueFactory` and, if needed, `cellFactory` for each `TableColumn`.

Comment: @Slaw how? can you show an example please?

Comment: This may help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJABIEED. _Note: Since lambdas have been added it is recommended to use your own `Callback` for `cellValueFactory` rather than using a `PropertyValueFactory` as the latter uses reflection._

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but you want to do the following: You have a table of which the first column holds the parameter name and then you have a new column for each file you parsed parameters from. If the parameter in the first column is found in the file, the value is presented in the respective column otherwise you show nothing. Is that correct? If this is true I guess what we should work on here is the design because what you are trying to do is a whole lot of work for such a simple functionality.

Comment: @omgBob yea, it's true.. I made it in SWT but I want compare my code to JavaFX so I'm just started to learn it and I need help...

Comment: Like @omgBob said, you may need to modify your design. Why not have a unique `TableView` for each file? It sounds like you want to have a `TableView` where each row is a _list_ of values. In other words, you're using each `TableColumn` as a row in a list, where the first column is the header. The `TableView` control was not designed for that. Maybe what you want is more like an Excel spreadsheet? If so, try looking at the [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) library—specifically, their [spreadsheet](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/) API.

Comment: That said, if you want to continue using a `TableView` I believe [fabian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52314459/6395627) gives a good idea on how to do what you want.

Comment: If you still want to use a TableView (maybe you just don't want to design your own Node), you may also make a TableView with the columns Parameter Name, Parameter Value and the name of the File the value was found it. Don't know if your example files are the full list but as far as i can see there are no duplicates so this solution would work fine.

Comment: I've edited again

Comment: The table from the SWT only contains 2 columns, I thought you wanted 3?

Comment: at the end of day you must have _one single list_ of whatever data item that has two properties (vs. the two lists you are still thinking of) those properties _are_ the columns. So start modeling your data such that it fits that requirement - there is no way around other than not using a TableView at all ;)

Comment: @omgBob I can have more than 2, its changing according to the number of loaded files.

Comment: The only other thing that comes to my mind is that you have x TableViews (each with one column), one for the parameter name and then one for each file. When you place them correctly it will look like only one table. But the focus and edit will look horribly so I suppose you disable them. If I were you I would redesign the stuff like @kleopatra said ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for a `TableView` is held in the `ObservableList` of the `items` property. A `TableView` is designed to hold a list of POJOs that contain various properties. Each of the properties will correspond to a `TableColumn` who obtains the value of these properties using a `Callback`.

Since you are browsing text files let's say you define a POJO like so:

```
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class TextFile {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    public final void setName(String name) { this.name.set(name); }
    public final String getName() { return name.get(); }
    public final StringProperty nameProperty() { return name; }

    private final LongProperty size = new SimpleLongProperty(this, "size");
    public final void setSize(long size) { this.size.set(size); }
    public final long getSize() { return size.get(); }
    public final LongProperty sizeProperty() { return size; }

    public TextFile() {}

    public TextFile(String name, long size) {
        setName(name);
        setSize(size);
    }

}
```

From this you'll want a `TableView` of `TextFile`s that has a `TableColumn` for `name` and a `TableColumn` for `size`. To tell a `TableColumn` how to obtain the correct value you set the `cellValueFactory` with the appropriate `Callback`. This `Callback` accepts a `TableColumn.CellDataFeatures` and returns an `ObservableValue`. If the `ObservableValue` changes the `TableColumn` will update the item of the corresponding `TableCell`.

```
ObservableList<TextFile> files = ...;
TableView<TextFile> table = new TableView<>();
table.setItems(files);

TableColumn<TextFile, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
nameCol.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().nameProperty());
table.getColumns().add(nameCol);

TableColumn<TextFile, Number> sizeCol = new TableColumn<>("Size");
sizeCol.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().sizeProperty());
table.getColumns().add(sizeCol);
```

Note that each `TextFile` in `files` is a row in the `TableView`.

Comment: @Ang3lStyl3X I'm not sure I understand the format of your data. Once you load from the file do you have a one-to-one relationship between name and value? Like a `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: @Ang3lStyl3X Can you post an example text file and indicate what data you want to go in what column? And are there a variable number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like that:

```
TableColumn< YourObject, String> col = new TableColumn<>();
col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("nameOfThePropertyYouWantToDisplay");
TableColumn< YourObject, String> col2 ....

TableView < YourObject> table = new TableView();
table.setItems(observableListOfYourObject);
```

Look here for a detailed description: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

Comment: no.. I'm looking for something else.. I have columns, I just need to use each row in specific column to add items list to it.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the item type accordingly. Your description indicates the following properties:

- The table data is not edited once it's loaded.
- You cannot hardcode the number of files.

Therefore a suitable choice of data structure would be `List<String>`. Each list contains one element for every column.

```
public void initializeTableColumns(TableView<List<String>> table, File file, File... files) {
    List<String> fileItems = readFile(file);
    TableColumn<List<String>, String> column = new TableColumn<>(file.getName());
    column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().get(0));
    table.getColumns().add(column);

    for (String s : fileItems) {
        List<String> row = new ArrayList<>(files.length + 1);
        row.add(s);
        table.getItems().add(row);
    }

    for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < files.length; fileIndex++) {
        File f = files[fileIndex];

        fileItems = readFile(f);
        int itemCount = Math.min(fileItems.size(), table.getItems().size());
        // add items from file
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            table.getItems().get(i).add(fileItems.get(i));
        }
        if (itemCount <= table.getItems.size()) {
            // fill items that may be missing
            for (int i = itemCount; i < table.getItems().size(); i++) {
                table.getItems().get(i).add(null);
            }
        } else {
            // add missing rows
            for (int i = table.getItems.size(); i < itemCount; i++) {
                List<String> row = new ArrayList<>(files.length + 1);
                for (int j = 0; j <= fileIndex; j++) {
                    row.add(null);
                }
                row.add(fileItems.get(i));
                table.getItems().add(row);
            }
        }

        final index = fileIndex + 1;
        column = new TableColumn<>(f.getName());
        column.setTableColumn(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().get(index)));
        table.getColumns().add(column);
    }
}
```